# Min/ Max dates based on results of query

Tags: oracle

Need to find the Max and Min dates using the results of a query. The following query is working but have to add additional code to find the Max/ Min dates based on its results (results of dates from last 2 AND statements). Using Oracle SQL Developer.

```
SELECT SO.COM_DATE, SO.RAISED_DATE, SE.SERV_NO, SO.OR_NO
FROM S_ORDER SO, S_SERV SE
WHERE SO.CU_NO='286243' AND SE.SERV_NO='69780'
AND SUBSTR (SE.ACCT_NO, 1,8)=SO.CU_NO
AND SO.RAISED_DATE +4/24 BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND TO_DATE('2018-07-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Tried to add the Max/ Min statements to the end  but getting an Invalid Statement error. Thanks for any help.

Results of the query will therefore be:

```
COM_DATE | RAISED_DATE | SERV_NO | OR_NO
2018-07-05 | 2018-07-04 | 69780 | GHYUYR     
2018-06-27 | 2018-06-08 | 69780 | HHUYTT  
2018-03-10 | 2018-02-04 | 69780 | JJUHYT
```

Therefore, after the Min/ Max code added, the results should ONLY return:

```
COM_DATE | RAISED_DATE | 
2018-07-05 (max)| 2018-02-04 (min)
```

Comment: Do you want all the results from this query **plus the min and max dates**? Or only the min and max dates?

Answer (score 1):

This should work to get the min and max date for you.

```
SELECT MIN(RAISED_DATE), MAX(RAISED_DATE), MIN(COM_DATE), MAX(COM_DATE)
FROM   (SELECT SO.COM_DATE, SO.RAISED_DATE, SE.SERV_NO, SO.OR_NO
        FROM S_ORDER SO, S_SERV SE
        WHERE SO.CU_NO='286243' AND SE.SERV_NO='69780'
        AND SUBSTR (SE.ACCT_NO, 1,8)=SO.CU_NO
        AND SO.RAISED_DATE +4/24 BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND TO_DATE('2018-07-30','YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

If you want the other data in the query you will need to add a group by

```
SELECT SO.COM_DATE, MIN(SO.RAISED_DATE), MAX(SO.RAISED_DATE), SE.SERV_NO, SO.OR_NO
FROM S_ORDER SO, S_SERV SE
WHERE SO.CU_NO='286243' AND SE.SERV_NO='69780'
AND SUBSTR (SE.ACCT_NO, 1,8)=SO.CU_NO
AND SO.RAISED_DATE +4/24 BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND TO_DATE('2018-07-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY SO.COM_DATE, SE.SERV_NO, SO.OR_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the results from the query **plus the min and max dates** in 2 additional columns, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT SO.COM_DATE, SO.RAISED_DATE, SE.SERV_NO, SO.OR_NO,
       MIN(SO.RAISED_DATE) OVER () AS MIN_RAISED_DATE,
       MAX(SO.RAISED_DATE) OVER () AS MAX_RAISED_DATE
FROM  -- the rest of the query unchanged
```